# How to set the selection items for CComboBox to be the CString array all at once?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am look for the combobox to display 4 rows where the first row shows "a", 2nd row shows "b"..."c"..."d"

```
cb1 = new CComboBox;
cb1->Create( WS_VSCROLL | CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, CRect(20,200,200, 300), this, 30 );

CString itemSet[] = {"a","b","c","d"};


//I am to set the array all at once with out doing each itme ??
cb1.AddString(itemSet); //fails
```

Comment: The question is not very clear. Do you need different sets of options, so that you can choose between {a, b, c, d} or between {m, n, o, p}?

Comment: I made changes to make easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no function to do so in one go. You could do as Jeeva suggest, a simple loop traversing your array:

```
CString itemSet[] = {"a","b","c","d"};   
for (int i = 0; i < _countof(itemSet); ++i)
{
    cb1.AddString(itemSet[i]);
}
```

However, if you are going to use it often, you could create your own CCombobox derived class and add a function that does it.

```
class CMyCombo : public CCombobox
{
public:
    CMyCombo();
    void AddStrings(const CString* strings, int num);

    // ...
}


void CMyCombo::AddStrings(const CString* strings, int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        cb1.AddString(strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Actually, I would probably use a container, such as `std::vector` or `CStringArray`, but you get the idea.

By the way, if you are using strings that could be localized, you should not rely on strings only. A better approach can be found [here](http://www.flounder.com/combobox.htm).

One last thing: there's usually no need to create controls on the fly. It's usually easier to create member variables for them.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
    CString arr[2] = {_T("A"),_T("B")};

    for(int i =0 ;i <2; i++)
    {
        m_ctrlCombo.AddString(arr[i]);
    }
```